# Shopping Cart Rules Page Not Loading Correctly in Admin Area

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have recently inherited a Magento 1.9.2.4 site from a previous developer. When we try to add new Shopping cart price rules, we get a blank screen on the add new rule page. The page looks like it is getting a Prototype error, but cant seem to find how to fix this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Please see screenshots attached for the issue and the console log error.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I'm also getting the same blank page on a Magento 1.9.2.4 site when trying to add or edit shopping cart price rules.

Same error appears when inspecting the page errors about prototype.js, did you find a solution?

EDIT: Just found the solution. Go to Admin/Configuration/Advanced and enable

"Amasty_Base" and "Amasty_Xcoupon"

If there is another coupon extension being used, make sure it's enabled.

These got disabled somehow but once I enabled them again, the shopping cart price rules page appeared properly again.

Comment: Why would someone downvote my answer? Weird...